# illegal mix of collations in MySQL for operation =

Tags: mysql, collation, notin

I have a table `abc` that has 2 columns:

`id INT(3)`
`name VARCHAR(10)`

The default collation for this table and for all of its column is `utf8_unicode_ci`

I then have another table `xyz` that has 2 columns:

`id INT(3)`
`name VARCHAR(10)`

The default collation for this table and for all of its column is also `utf8_unicode_ci`

Now I am firing this `select` statement:

`SELECT NAME
 FROM abc
 WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM XYZ);`

I have checked the collations of both the tables and they are same, still, it gives me the error : 
`illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci implicit) and (utf8_unicode_ci implicit) for operation =`

I also tried an alternate for `NOT IN` i.e. by using `LEFT JOIN` but it still gives me the same error.

I have been stuck on this for a long time now. Any help is appreciated.Thanks

Comment: "I have checked the collations of both the tables and they are same, still, it gives me the error : illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci implicit) and (utf8_unicode_ci implicit) for operation =" learn one thing well programming computers do not lie..

Comment: show `SHOW CREATE TABLE abc` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE xyz` outputs.

Comment: The full query and error would help too since I can't see how you would get a collation error comparing two INTEGER ID values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A likely workaround:

```
SELECT NAME
    FROM abc
    LEFT JOIN XYZ  USING(ID)
    WHERE XYZ.ID IS NULL;
```

Another help may be

```
SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```